# Как вытащить название ссылки из href?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть сайт со списком фильмов, название каждого - ссылка. Как спарсить само название если оно находится в href?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'accept': accept,'user-agent':user-agent}

base_url = url

def parse (base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'lister-item mode- 
 advanced'})
        for div in divs:
            name = div.find('a', attrs = {'href': ???}).text
            print(name)
    else: 
        print('ERROR')

parse(base_url, headers)
```

Для наглядности, выглядит это вот так:
[image: Как достать название?]

Comment: XPath вам в руки. BeautifulSoup конечно хорошо, но я бы брал простейший ElementTree. Решение в одно выражение XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Если нужно парсить содержимое (текст) ссылки

Попробуйте вот такое решение, основанное на возможности BS возвращать список объектов, который соответствует универсальному селектору.

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'accept': accept,'user-agent':user-agent}

base_url = url

def parse (base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.select('div.lister-item.mode-advanced')
        for div in divs:
            links = div.select('a') # читать примечание после кода
            name = links[0].text if links else '' # если в div этого типа может быть только одна ссылка (если их больше - остальные проигнорируются)
            # name = ', '.join([link.text for link in links]) # если в div этого типа может быть несколько ссылок, так можно получить все их названия через запятую
            # name = [link.text for link in links] # а вот так можно получить все названия всех ссылок, но уже в виде списка
    else: 
        print('ERROR')

parse(base_url, headers)
```

Примечание:
Если нужно выбирать какие-то конкретные ссылки (например, только начинающиеся с `https://`), можно также преобразовать селектор таким образом:

```py
...
links = div.select('a[href^="https://"]')
...
```

Подробнее о селекторах по атрибутам можно почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

## Если нужно парсить адрес ссылки

> Как спарсить само название если оно находится в href?

Если же вы всё-таки имели в виду парсинг `href`, то ссылку можно получать следующим образом:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'accept': accept,'user-agent':user-agent}

base_url = url

def parse (base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})
        for div in divs.find_all('a', href=True):
            name = div['href']
            print("Найдена ссылка:", name)
    else: 
        print('ERROR')
parse(base_url, headers)
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/)